# install GNU m4 1.4 or later on OSX

Tags: macos, installation, terminal, homebrew

I'm interested to install GNU m4 1.4 or later into `/usr/bin/`, I installed Homebrew, like this, `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"`, to be able to insall `bfgminer`, but when I got to `brew install bfgminer`–more or less following [these instructions](http://blog.nwoolls.com/2013/04/24/bitcoin-mining-on-mac-os-x-cgminer-bfgminer/)–I get told that `need GNU m4 1.4 or later: /usr/bin/m4`.

Can anyone tell me how I install GNU m4 1.4 or later on OSX 10.8.5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was to install the "Command Line Tools" from within Xcode. `⌘,` opens preferences and the install button for the "Command Line Tools" can be found in the "Downloads."

Comment: I had to run `xcode-select --install` to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: didn't help. I have installed

Answer (score 15):

*Old question but i try to give new related solution*

I run :

> phpize

then got

```
autom4te: need GNU m4 1.4 or later: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/m4
```

because `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.8/bin/phpize` always try to use it own `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/m4`

Solve problem by:

- `brew install m4`

brew installed `m4` to **/usr/local/opt/m4**

- `mv /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/m4 /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/m4_backup`
- `ln -s /usr/local/opt/m4/bin/m4 /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/m4`
- `phpize`
- `unlink /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/m4`
- `mv /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/m4_backup /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/m4`

hope this will help wrong `m4` bin problem

Answer (score 4):

On the other hand, if you have homebrew installed already, you can still look for m4 in other places.  I just tried running "brew install m4" and it returns "homebrew/dupes/m4".  So I run "sudo brew install homebrew/dupes/m4" instead.  Now it installed m4 1.4.17 to my computer from gnu.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I ran this in the terminal: `xcode-select --install`

Then clicked install on the popup.

Answer (score 0):

Was having a similar issue trying to install the PHP 8.0 redis extension on macos:

```
pecl install redis
```

It complained:

```
autom4te: error: need GNU m4 1.4 or later: /usr/local/opt/m4/bin/m4
autoheader: error: '/usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.71/bin/autom4te' failed with exit status: 1
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

But checking the m4 version showed `m4 (GNU M4) 1.4.19`

```
/usr/local/opt/m4/bin/m4 --version
```

My solution was pretty simple: just had to run `sudo pecl install redis` and it worked fine, just did not work without sudo

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the same issue by executing `brew reinstall m4`.